# combine two half images using html and css

Tags: html, css, image

I want to combine two half images using the css like in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/u78bQ/) fiddle.

I want another same radius half circle to combine it.

Here it is not the image, Its a `div`.

```
<div class="half-circle">
 <img src = "http://i.imgur.com/CnjuZOS.jpg">
</div>

<div class = "other-half-circle"> 
 <img src = "http://i.imgur.com/yAiPyc4.jpg">
</div>
```

Here's my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nd3mekt3/)

Comment: Why use the image , it is easily created to css.

Comment: make the image background transparent `png` transparent to be able to achieve

Comment: Why you want to do this? either use both images in one div but  before use png as white background is coming in both images.

Comment: @Jainam I'll be having two images. Suppose one is a full circle image and then I have to put another image to cover the half of that image. 

I hope it is clear now

Answer (score 0):

I updated your jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nd3mekt3/1/

The CSS:

```
.half-circle{
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
  height: 500px;
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/CnjuZOS.jpg');
  background-position: top right; 
}

.other-half-circle{
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
  height: 500px;
  background-position: top right;
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/yAiPyc4.jpg');
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="other-half-circle"></div>
<div class="half-circle"></div>
```

This way, your 2 half circles are floated next to each other, making a whole circle.

Answer (score 0):

**Please Check the given below snippet.**

**I have attached the two images.**

**Thanks**

```css
.main-blk{width:500px;height:500px;position:relative;}
.half-circle{position:absolute;width:250px;top:0;right:0;overflow:hidden;}
.half-circle img{left: -250px;
    position: relative;}
.other-half-circle{position:absolute;width:250px;top:0;left:0;overflow:hidden;}
```

```html
<div class="main-blk">
<div class = "other-half-circle">  
  <img src = "http://i.imgur.com/yAiPyc4.jpg">
</div>
<div class="half-circle">
  <img src = "http://i.imgur.com/CnjuZOS.jpg">
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manizm/akjLu2d4/7/)

The CSS:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  width:200px;
}
.circle-left, .circle-right {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-right:0;
  border-radius: 200px 0px 0px 200px;
  position: absolute;
}
img {
  margin: 10px -3px;
  padding: 0;
}
.circle-right {
  transform: scale(-1, 1);
  clip: rect(0px,100px,200px,0px);
  right: 0;
  z-index:1;
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <img class="circle-left" src="http://i.imgur.com/h6YimPp.jpg" />
  <img class="circle-right" src="http://i.imgur.com/yAiPyc4.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akjLu2d4/4/), Now how do I cover the half of the circle with that brown color half circle

Comment: you would first need to use images with transparent background, then you can wrap both images in a single container and make it relative and the images absolute. Give same width to the container as image. Last, to the .circle-right class, give it right: 0; property.
Here is the fiddle without transparent bg pictures: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/manizm/akjLu2d4/5/)

Comment: one of my image is missing from your fiddle

Comment: its not missing..its under the .circle-right. Just give container 250px width or change the z-index of .circle-right and you will see.
This example won't work unless you are using transparent background images which is png

Comment: there you go. Just added clip property to the half circle image so it can be cropped from left [check here](http://jsfiddle.net/manizm/akjLu2d4/7/)
Although again, I would suggest you to use .png for real